# Power BI: How do I edit the query in Import mode

Tags: powerbi

when I created a Power BI report, I chose "Import" mode and in advanced options specified a query as:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
```

Quite a few pages have been added now and many charts. Now, I need to edit the query to reduce the refresh time. New query needs a WHERE clause as:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE tags LIKE '%customer%'
```

But when I navigate to Data Source Settings, the query box is disabled. Any idea how to edit the query without recreating all charts again?

Comment: It may be also helpful [Power BI: Edit Existing SQL Query](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/powerbi-edit-existing-sql-query/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps in power bi desktop:

***Home tab > Edit query button drop down > click edit query > in query setting as shown in below image > click source setting icon > and then edit your sql query***

[image]